# SenchaTouch 2 : Same toolbar used across the views is firing the same event multiple times

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

BackGround:
I am using the same toolbar in all my views which is defined in a separate view. This toolbar has four buttons. Since this button has 'id' attribute,
tap event on one button from a view will trigger similar tap events from other views as well since the same toolbar is used across the views.

My Toolbar is as below.

```
Ext.define("WU.view.WUToolBar", {
    extend: "Ext.Toolbar",
    alias: "widget.wuToolBar",
    xtype:"wuToolBar",
    config: {
        docked : 'bottom',
        cls : 'tabBar',
        ui:'widgetBottombarUI',
        items : [ 
            {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'My Account',
            cls : 'profileTabBar',
            id : 'myProfileButton',
            listeners : {
                tap : function(button, e, eOpts) {
                    console.log('myProfileButton is clicked');
                }
            }, 
            {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Help',
            cls : 'helpTabBar',
            id : 'helpTabButton',
            listeners : {
                tap : function(button, e, eOpts) {
                    console.log('helpButton is clicked');
                }
            }, 
        ]
    },
});
```

I am adding this to my different views in the items config as below.

```
xtype : 'wuToolBar'
```

So, tap event on a button in a single view will fires the tap event from all the views since this toolbar is shared across the pages. If I am removing the 
id attribute then application works fine but I need to assign the id to the button since I have to access them using `getCmp` method.

Comment: If you're using the toolbar more than once, you should most definitely not be using ids, since they should be unique across your whole application. This is really poor practice.

Comment: Hi Evan. Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is I have to access the buttons declared inside the toolbar from other places. I believe, i can do this only using getCmp method. So for that, I need to declare Ids for the buttons inside the toolbar. Please suggest

Comment: That's not true at all, there are plenty of ways to access components, look at child(), down() and query() on Ext.container.Container. Also look at the itemId configuration, an id that is local to a container.

Comment: Hi Evan. Thanks for the pointers. Please move it to the answer so I can accept the same.

Comment: No worries. I didn't really answer it, so just put your solution in there and mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is on all views, then I would suggest adding it in your app.js, and then simply add to the Viewport when you move from screen to screen:

In app.js:

```
...
launch: function() {
  ...
  // Add static components
  Ext.Viewport.add([
    {
      xtype: 'wuToolBar'
      docked: 'bottom' // I would recommend moving this out of your customized config
    }
  ]);
  ...
},
...
```

You can add a view later using the same method (`Ext.Viewport.add(...)`), or you can use the  [`Ext.navigation.View` component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View).

Comment: I cant add this to my viewport since I dont want this toolbar to appear on all my pages. Thanks for the reply @jakerella.

Comment: Aah... well, I'm sure you'll get it. There's always more than one way to get things done in JS.